# Reload Grid not working for multiple jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, grid

I am using jqgrid.  My page has three tabs and each tab contains a different grid.  All grids have different ids.  The content of tabs is fetched via AJAX request lazily.  Now after all three grids are rendered and I try to reload grid via function

```
jQuery("#myOffersTable").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Only the grid which loaded last reloads and it doesn't work for other grids.

For example, if grids load seq is :  1-2-3 then this code will only work for grid 3
but if seq is 3-2-1 then it will work only for 1.

But if I try reloading grids using reload button on navigator bar it works fine.

#### Update:

I am using Struts2 jQuery Plugin.It uses jqGrid 3.6.4
I load json data using ajax.

Below is the definition of my grid.

```
<div id='t1'>
    <s:url id="offersurl" action="offers"/>
     
    <sjg:grid 
        id="offerstable" 
        caption="Customer Examples"
        autoencode="false" 
        dataType="json" 
        href="%{offersurl}"         
        
        pager="true"       
        navigator="true"
        navigatorAdd="false"
        navigatorDelete="false"
        navigatorEdit="false"
        navigatorSearch="false"
                
        gridModel="offers"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
        onCompleteTopics="addAcceptButtons"
        filter="true"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false" search="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="offeror" index="offeror" title="Offeror" sortable="true" search="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="itemOffered" index="itemOffered" title="ItemOffered" sortable="false" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="quantityOffered" index="quantityOffered" title="QuantityOffered" sortable="false" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','lt','gt']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="expectedItem" index="expectedItem" title="ExpectedItem" sortable="false" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="expectedQuantity" index="expectedQuantity" title="ExpectedQuantity" sortable="false" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','lt','gt']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="acceptOffer" index="acceptOffer"  title="Accept Offer" search="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>    
    
</div>
```

I have three such grids all have different ids and all that stuff.

There is a search button above each grid which calls the following function with parameter sel.sel is 1,2 or 3 corresponding to each grid

```
function search(sel)
{   
    alert("search");
    if(sel==1)
    {       
        tradeOffer = $("#games").val();
        var srchValue = $("#srchoptions").val();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                data: {'gameId': tradeOffer},             
            });
        jQuery("#offerstable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"offers.action?q=1&srch="+srchValue,page:1});
        //jQuery("#offerstable").trigger('reloadGrid');
        $("#offerstable").trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
    else if(sel==2)
    {           
            myTradeOfferGame = $("#my").val();          
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    data: {'gameId': myTradeOffer},               
                });
            jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"offers.action?q=1",page:1});
            jQuery("#myOffersTable").trigger('reloadGrid');                 
    }
    else if(sel==3)
    {           
            acceptedTradeOfferGame = $("#accepted").val();          
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    data: {'gameId': acceptedTradeOffer},             
                });
            jQuery("#acceptedtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"offers.action?q=1",page:1});
            jQuery("#acceptedtable").trigger('reloadGrid');                 
    }
    
}
```

The function gets called for each grid but

```
jQuery("#acceptedtable").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

works for only grid loaded last.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? How you load data into the grids (ajax, xml, local)? Could you post a small code example, which have the problem. Tip: data (xml/json) which jqGrid received from sever can be saved in a file and instead of loading dynamic data one can load a static file with the same results. If one can reproduce the problem, one will find also a solution or a workaround.

Comment: Hi Oleg,
Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all in your code you define variables `myTradeOfferGame` and `acceptedTradeOfferGame` (inside of `else if(sel==2)` and `else if(sel==3)`), but use `myTradeOffer` and `acceptedTradeOffer`. It looks like errors.

Second: The urls inside of `else if(sel==2)` and `else if(sel==3)` look another as in the first table: URLs are static, so why one should set this value every time? Probably you want to add in all urls the part with `$("#srchoptions").val()`? You should fix these problem yourself.

In your code one can see, that you use `$.ajaxSetup` which change global settings of `$.ajax`. If you change this 3 times only the last one will be saved. If only one from three setting work at one refresh, `$.ajaxSetup` is nevertheless not the best way. jqGrid has parameter `ajaxGridOptions`, which set parameters of `$.ajax` per table (see [Setting the content-type of requests performed by jQuery jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731)).

Moreover jqGrid (every instance) has a parameter `postData`, which will be forward to `$.ajax` as `data` parameter. So you can use this parameter in the jqGrid definition. If you want that the data which you place as `postData` will be **reloaded** during **every** `trigger('reloadGrid')` you can just define `postData` using function. The default behavior of `$.ajax` is to test whether the field of `data` parameter is function, it it is so, `$.ajax` call this function the get the value. So your code could look like following:

```
// definition of 3 jqGrids
jQuery("#offerstable").jqGrid ({
    postData: {'gameId': function() { return $("#games").val(); } },
    //...
});
jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid ({
    postData: {'gameId': function() { return $("#my").val(); } },
    //...
});
jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid ({
    postData: {'gameId': function() { return $("#accepted").val(); } },
    //...
});

if(sel==1)
{       
    jQuery("#offerstable")
    .jqGrid('setGridParam',
            {url:"offers.action?q=1&srch="+encodeURIComponent($("#srchoptions").val()),
            page:1})
    .trigger('reloadGrid');
} else //...
// ...
```

By the way if you use HTTP GET for data request, the parameters from `data` parameter (`postData`) will be just **appended** to the url (with placing '?' and '&' like one do this usual).

The final code can be something like following:

```
// definition of 3 jqGrids
jQuery("#offerstable").jqGrid ({
    url:"offers.action", 
    postData: {'q': 1,
               'gameId': function() { return $("#games").val(); },
               'srch': function() { return $("#srchoptions").val(); },
    //...
});
jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid ({
    url:"offers.action", 
    postData: {'q': 1,
               'gameId': function() { return $("#my").val(); } },
    //...
});
jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid ({
    url:"offers.action", 
    postData: {'q': 1,
               'gameId': function() { return $("#accepted").val(); } },
    //...
});
```

and

```
if(sel==1) {
    jQuery("#offerstable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
} else if (sel==2) {
    jQuery("#myOffersTable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
} else if (sel==3) {
    jQuery("#acceptedtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and effort Oleg.But it doesn't solve my problem.Above recommendations do make the code elegant but the problem still remains the same.


Below is the code snippet
        jQuery("#acceptedtable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"offers.action?q=1",page:1});
        jQuery("#acceptedtable").trigger('reloadGrid'); 


Here i am setting the url and then triggering reload event.No matter what ajaxSettings were the grid should reload but it doesn't.Probably there is something else going on like a new grid overwriting previous grids handler or something like that.

Comment: And even after those AjaxSetup setting the reload button on navigator works fine it just the trigger('reloadGrid') thats not working.Any idea if i can trigger the same event which navigator search button triggers.

Comment: Use fiddler (see https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to verify whether your request are send (replace localhost in urls to ipv4.fiddler during the tests). What you write sound like a cashing problem. If it is so, there are different ways for workaround. Just delete local cash before a refreshing of data. If the data will be refreshed after emptying of cash, I can post you references how to fix the problem (for example `cache` parameter of jQuery.ajax function).