# Populate jqGrid from ASMX

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asmx

I have been struggling to get this grid to populate.

This returns my 2 rows but the cells are empty?

I would prefer to do it all with the jqGrid (so with a separate Ajax call, but I couldn't get it working). Any help would be much appreciated.

The JSON the [ASMX](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asmx/info) returns:

```
{"__type":"myproject.jq_grid","page":1,"total":1,"records":2,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","donald","duck"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","daffy","duck"]}]}
```

Client side: scripts in the same order,

1. jquery-1.5.min.js
2. jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js
3. grid.locale-en.js
4. jquery.jqGrid.min.js

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#list1").jqGrid({
           datatype: function (postdata) {
               var params = new Object();
               params.page_index = postdata.page;
               params.page_size = postdata.rows;
               params.sort_index = postdata.sidx;
               params.sort_direction = postdata.sord;

               $.ajax({
                   url: "../service/contact_service.asmx/contact_jq_grid",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: JSON.stringify(params),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   error: function (data, textStatus) {
                       alert("Error loading json");
                   },
                   success: function (data, st) {
                       if (st == "success") {
                           var results = (typeof data.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data.d + ')') : data.d;

                           $("#list1")[0].addJSONData(eval("(" + JSON.stringify(results) + ")"));
                       }
                   }
               });
           },
           colNames: ["contact_id", "first_name", "last_name"],
           colModel: [{ name: "contact_id", index: "contact_id", width: 100 },
                      { name: "first_name", index: "first_name", width: 150 },
                      { name: "last_name", index: "last_name", width: 150}],
           pager: "#pager1",
           rowNum: 10,
           rowList: [10, 20, 30],
           sortname: "contact_id",
           sortorder: "asc",
           viewRecords: true,
           jsonReader: {
               root: "rows",
               page: "page",
               total: "total",
               records: "records",
               repeatitems: false,
               id: "id",
               cell: "cell"
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Server side:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function contact_jq_grid( _
  ByVal page_index As Integer, ByVal page_size As Integer, _
  ByVal sort_index As String, ByVal sort_direction As String)
  As jq_grid

    Dim jq_grid As New jq_grid

    Dim contacts As List(Of contact) = _
      contact_functions.get_contacts_aw(1, page_index - 1, page_size, sort_index, sort_direction)

    For i As Integer = 0 To contacts.Count - 1
        Dim row As New jq_grid.row()

        row.id = contacts(i).contact_id
        row.cell.Add(contacts(i).contact_id)
        row.cell.Add(contacts(i).first_name)
        row.cell.Add(contacts(i).last_name)

        jq_grid.rows.Add(row)
    Next

    jq_grid.page = page_index
    jq_grid.records = contacts.Count
    jq_grid.total = Math.Ceiling(contacts.Count / page_size)

    Return jq_grid
End Function

Public Class jq_grid
    Private _page As Integer
    Private _total As Integer
    Private _records As Integer
    Private _rows As List(Of row)

    Public Property page() As Integer
        Get
            Return _page
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _page = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property total() As Integer
        Get
            Return _total
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _total = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property records() As Integer
        Get
            Return _records
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _records = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property rows() As List(Of row)
        Get
            Return _rows
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of row))
            _rows = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        rows = New List(Of row)
    End Sub

    Public Class row
        Private _id As Integer
        Private _cell As List(Of String)

        Public Property id() As Integer
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property cell() As List(Of String)
            Get
                Return _cell
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
                _cell = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            cell = New List(Of String)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main error is that you use `repeatitems: false` in the `jsonReader`, but you construct the data for `repeatitems: true`.

Another error: if the JSON data returned from the server really are in the format like you posted (I am not sure that it is so), that you should not use `data.d` in the `success` handle. I suppose, that you included as JSON not the server response, but the value of `results` variable where `data.d` are used.

You use very old code template with `datatype` as a function. You can easy rewrite the code without it (see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542) for example). Moreover if you really need to use renamed parameters like `page_index` instead of `page` you can better use `prmNames` to do this.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your reply. You were correct, repeatitems: true fixed it. Also you were right about the JSON.

I have found the documentation to prmNames but are there any examples as this seems to do exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have posted my updated client side code below but it doesn't fire off my service. could you have a look please.