# jqGrid with Enabled Advanced Search different calls to the server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on a page wrapped inside an ASP.NET web part. Here is it's definition:

```
$("#referent_grid").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= SPContext.Current.Site.Url %>' + wsBaseUrl + 'ReferentService.asmx/ListReferents',
    colNames: ['Full Name', 'Phone Number', 'Email', 'Department'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 240, align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },
        { name: 'PhoneNumber', index: 'PhoneNumber', width: 120, align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },
        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 180, align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },
        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 180, align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: "ReferentID"
    },
    pager: $('#referent_grid_pager'),
    sortname: 'FullName',
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: '300',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    caption: 'Referent List'
});
$("#referent_grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#referent_grid_pager',
    { add: true, addtitle: 'Add Referent', edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit Referent',
      del: true, deltitle: 'Delete Referent', refresh: true, refreshtitle: 'Refresh data',
      search: true, searchtitle: 'Advanced search filters',
      addfunc: addReferent, editfunc: editReferent
    },
    {}, // default settings for edit
    {}, // default settings for add
    { // define settings for Delete 
        mtype: "post", reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        url: '<%= SPContext.Current.Site.Url %>' + wsBaseUrl + 'ReferentService.asmx/DeleteReferent',
        resize: false,
        serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
            return JSON.stringify({ referentID: postdata.id });
        },
        afterSubmit: function (data, postdata) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            return [true, ''];
        }
    },
    { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
    {}
);
```

As you can see I have Advanced Search enabled. The problem I am facing to is that the first time the page is called the jqGrid calls the `ListReferents` method without passing the filters parameter as you can see in the following screenshot from Fiddler

[image: First call]

When I click on the `refresh` button of the jqGrid it calls the `ListReferents` method passing the filters parameter as you can see in the following screenshot from Fiddler

[image: Call from refresh]

To arrange this I have defined two methods inside my web service but the first method does never get called while the second is.

```
[WebMethod]
public JQGridData ListReferents(string _search, string nd, string rows, string page, string sidx, string sord) {
    return ListReferents(_search, nd, rows, page, sidx, sord, string.Empty);
}

[WebMethod]
public JQGridData ListReferents(string _search, string nd, string rows, string page, string sidx, string sord, string filters) {
    // method code here
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: set reloadaftersubmit to false and call refresh by force

Comment: @MLS: do you mean on the delete params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **all** parameters of the web service should be defined. Only 5 standard parameters :`_search`, `rows`, `page`, `sidx`, `sord` are always defined in the request to the server. So you have to test inside of `serializeGridData` whether the `filter` property is defined in the `postData`. If not defined you should set it to `null` or to the empty string `""`:

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542) an example). It should solve your problem.

Additionally you should remove traling commas in the `colModel` definition (camma before ']').

One more small suggestion. You can simplify the column definition in the `colModel`. First of all you can remove `align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text'` properties which are default (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). Moreover is you have some common settings in the most of columns you can redefines the default values for `colModel` of the grid with respect `cmTemplate` parameters:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 240 },
    { name: 'PhoneNumber', index: 'PhoneNumber', width: 120 },
    { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 180 },
    { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 180 }
],
cmTemplate: { searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} }
```

see more about the column templates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856).