# jqGrid in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: jqgrid

```
<table id="UsersGrid"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#UsersGrid').jqGrid({
            colNames: ['Online', 'Computer', 'IP', 'User'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'IsOnline', width: 100, index: 'IsOnline', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne']} },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} },
                { name: 'IP', index: 'IP', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} },
                { name: 'User', index: 'User', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} }
              ],
            height: 250,
            datatype: getDataType
        });
    });

    function getDataType() {
        var grid = $("#UsersGrid");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/GridTest/GridTestService.asmx/GetData",
            data: jqGridSettings(grid),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                jqGridDataReceived(response.d, grid);
            }
        });
    }

    function jqGridSettings(grid) {
        return "{}";

        var settings = {

        };

        return JSON.stringify(settings);
    }

    function jqGridDataReceived(json, grid) {
        var rows = JSON.parse(json).rows;

        grid.clearGridData();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            grid.addRowData(i + 1, rows[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to pass the original search parameters to the server-side, how can I retrieve them with javascript?

Namely, where can I get the grid's `postData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that  the origin of the problem which you try to solve is the `datatype: getDataType` parameter which you use. You use some very old code example from the time of vary old jqGrid versions. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542) for an example how you can call ASMX web service using `datatype: 'json'` and additional `ajaxGridOptions` and `serializeGridData`parameters.

If you do want to use "retro style" with `datatype` as a function you can use `postData` parameter and define `getDataType` as `function getDataType(postdata) {...`. The `postdata` parameter contains all information which you need.