# jqGrid calling WebService (asmx) using json

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, jqgrid

I've got a jqGrid setup to post to a URL using the content type of application/json:

```
$("#jqCategoryGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',        
    url: "Webservices/TroubleTicketCategory.asmx/getCategoryData",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    // **UPDATE - This is the fix, as per Oleg's response**
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
        if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
        if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
        //if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
});
```

The problem is that the jqGrid is still trying to pass parameters using a non-json format so I'm getting an error "Invalid JSON Primitive"

Is there a way to instruct the jqGrid to serialize the data using Json?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I edited the provided source code in my question to include the fix I used, which came from Oleg's response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include JSON serialization of the posted data for example with respect of json2.js which can be downloaded from http://www.json.org/js.html:

```
serializeRowData: function (data) { return JSON.stringify(data); }
```

Comment: How do I do this? From all I can see, the jqGrid is black-boxed and handles all data serialization in the background. Is there a method or property or something I can specify in the init of the grid that instructs it to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731 I showed a code fragment of jqGrid which use `serializeRowData`. With respect of this function you have FULL control under the data sent to server. You have as `data` an object with data which will be send and you can convert there in a string how you want without restrictions. Moreover the full code of jqGrid you can free download  and study some other features. So it is not a black-box. It is an open box I see.

Comment: The referenced URL you sent contains the answer. I'll update my post to reflect this.

One other question - is there a way to get my form edit to serialize the data? It doesn't appear to use the same "serializeGridData" as the main loading method uses.

Comment: To do this you should use `serializeEditData: function (data) { return return JSON.stringify(data); }`. You can use `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, serializeEditData: function (data) { return return JSON.stringify(data); }});` to ovewrite this parameters for all jqGrids