# jqgrid dataurl completion event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jQuery to get a list of suppliers for a part number. 
I then want to load some extra data about the supplier/part number combination once the edit form appears. The problem is that the dataurl method (which I am calling in the beforeInitData method) to get the suppliers does not complete before the beforeShowForm method executes. Therefore I do not have a supplier to look up when the form first loads. Is there a way to run the function after the dataUrl method completes to get the extra data?

I have tried [JQGrid editoptions dataurl not using ajax get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231099/jqgrid-editoptions-dataurl-not-using-ajax-get) and got it going but I know there will be conflicts because the ajaxSelectOptions method gets called for every request and sometimes my requests will be coming from different places with different requirements.

Here is the code that I am using for my grid:

```
jQuery("#receiptPartsTable").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",
{
    height:400,
    width:800,
    reloadAfterSubmit:false,
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeInitData: function(form)
    {
        var selectedPart = rowData.part;
        var selectedPartQty = rowData.qty;
        //Getting list of suppliers
        $("#receiptPartsTable").jqGrid('setColProp', 'supplier', { editoptions:{dataUrl:'getSuppliersForPart.php?part=' + rowData.part} });
    },
    beforeShowForm: function(form)
    {
        var selectedPart = rowData.part;
        var selectedPartQty = rowData.qty;
        $('#part').val(selectedPart);
        $('#qty').val(selectedPartQty);

        //$('#supplier').val() is not set yet; 
        var supplier = $('#supplier').val(); 

        //This method is getting called before there is a supplier
        getPartDetails(rowData.part, supplier);

        //Set up onChange listener. After selecting a supplier, get the part details
        $('#supplier').change(function() {
            var supplier = $('#supplier').val();
            getPartDetails(selectedPart, supplier);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted no definition of jqGrid which you use. The context in which you execute the above code is also not quite clear. Do you get `rowData` before from the currently selected row? Where you define it?

Nevertheless I think that you went in the correct direction and that you found already the correct way to solve the problem. The usage of `complete` callback of `ajaxSelectOptions` is probably the only way which you can use. You wrote about some "conflicts", but not posted more details.

I would recommend you to examine properties of `this` inside of `complete` callback. jqGrid set `context` option (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.common.js#L350)) of the `$.ajax` call (exactly like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10231660/315935) which you already found yourself). So you can use `this.elem`, `this.options` and `this.vl` inside of `complete` callback. `this.vl` is the value from the cell in case if editing of existing row. Typically it's the name of the option which will be selected. `this.options` has tree important properties which you can use: `this.options.dataUrl`, `this.options.id`, `this.options.name`. In case of form editing are the values `this.options.id` and `this.options.name` the same. In case of inline editing `this.options.id` will have rowid and `_` ad the prefix. It gives you the possibility to execute different code inside of `complete` callback for different selects where you use `dataUrl`.

One more remark. In the most cases you can remove call of `setColProp` from the `beforeInitData` and use the approach suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150307/315935) and [the another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067258/315935):

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    data: {
        id: function () {
            return $("#receiptPartsTable").getGridParam('selrow');
        },
        part: function () {
            return rowData.part;
        }
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        var columName = this.options.name, response = jqXHR.responseText;
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use just `editoptions: {dataUrl: "getSuppliersForPart.php"}` The URL will be appended with `part` and `id` parameters (see the above code). Instead of `id` you could use `getRowData` to get content from other columns based of rowid of currently selected row for example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't realize that I could use "this".