# How do i pass the id of the currently edited row to 'dataUrl' property during cell edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which is enabled for cell editing. I want to add the value of the `id` of the currently edited row to the url that is passed to the  `dataUrl` property of the `editoptions` attribute. How can i achieve this?

```
 {

  name:'selectBox2',
  index:'selectBox2',
  editable: true,
  edittype: 'select',
  editoptions:
  { 
      dataUrl : 'classes/form_db.php?id=????????',
      multiple:true, 
      size:5
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement the requirement. The choice depend mostly from the editing mode which you use and which you not specified in your question. First of all I would recommend you to try the way described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525607/315935). One more way I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913788/315935).

Comment: There are many ways of usage inline editing mode. For example usage of `formatter: "actions"`, usage of `inlineNav`, direct calling of `editRow` inside of different callbacks like `onSelectRow`, `ondblClickRow`, `beforeSelectRow` etc. Do you tried my suggest with the usage of `data` property of `ajaxSelectOptions`?

Comment: I followed the example but the code is not even called. This is what i did         `var assignedGridObj = $("#assignedGrid");`
        `assignedGridObj.jqGrid({`
           `ajaxSelectOptions: {`
                `data: {`
                    `courseId: function ()` 
                    `{`
                        `var selId =` `assignedGridObj.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');` 
                        `var dataObj =` `assignedGridObj.jqGrid('getRowData', selId);`
                        `return dataObj["course.id"];`
                    }
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu: we would spend much time if you post full JavaScript code which create jqGrid. You posted only ports of the code, but another not less important parts stay unknown for me. Could you append you question with the code?

Comment: I used `setGridParam` to set the `ajaxSelectOptions`. It is working now. Thanks